# Showing accepted answer on top when it is your own answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, sorting

So I noticed (currently true of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38192/issues-with-opening-a-tea-bag-on-shabbos)) that when the asker answers their own question and accepts that answer, this does not push the answer to the top.

What is seems strange to me is that if the votes on the accepted answer are equal to the other answers, it would seem that being the accepted answer should push it to the top of the answer list over answers with equivalent votes.

I'm wondering if this was discussed and rejected, or if it was just never asked for?

Comment: I'm going to guess "too much work for an edge case", but I don't actually know.

Comment: In light of my answer citing an official SE stance, I'm tagging this [meta-tag:status-declined].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As noted on the Stack Exchange blog, it's been considered and not adopted:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

> Now, there are some special rules around owner-accepted answers, to prevent gaming:…
>
> 2. **No change in sort order.** Normally, accepted answers are "docked" under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.

(A tip of my hat to [DoubleAA](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) for pointing me to the blog post.)